# Tool for transferring database changes?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, data-transfer

Is there a tool (open source / commercial) that can transfer structural and data changes between two databases residing on different Microsoft SQL servers (or MySql servers)?

Comment: SQL-server or MySQL? One of the tags doesn't belong... [sql-server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) or [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html)

Comment: So you can't imagine transferring data between MySQL and MSSQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The obvious answer, of course, is [Red Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/). Visual Studio Premium and Ultimate editions also provide a tool for [comparing schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435.aspx) [and data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833428.aspx) across databases.

Comment: The MSDN links you provided state that the functionality is only available in VS Ultimate and Premium - not Professional. Do you know differently (because I have VS Professional and I'd like to do this!).

Comment: Ah, no, you're quite correct. I misread, sorry.

Comment: Red Gate's MySQL Compare is on extended Beta right now: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/mysql-compare/

Comment: Update: MySQL Compare is now fully released and can be downloaded from http://mysql-compare.com/

Answer (score 0):

If your servers are both MySQL, then the community edition of SQLyog will copy table structure and/or data between servers.